# Remove whitespace and make all lowercase in a string for python

Tags: python, regex, string

How do I remove all whitespace from a string and make all characters lowercase in python?

Also, can I add this operation to the string prototype like I could in javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
''.join(c.lower() for c in s if not c.isspace())
```

No. Python is not Ruby.

Comment: Is regex something that is used less in python?

Comment: Regular expressions are... usually not required.

Comment: @DutrowLLC, they are usually not required BUT there are times when they are indispensable.

Comment: If you need speed, this is not the way to go, use John Machin's solution below. On 250k iterations using timeit, clocked this function at 2.14721894264, vs 0.402789115906 using the join split solution.

Comment: var = ''.join(c.lower() for c in var if not c.isspace())

Answer (score 32):

How about an uncomplicated **fast** answer? No `map`, no `for` loops, ...

```
>>> s = "Foo Bar " * 5
>>> s
'Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar '
>>> ''.join(s.split()).lower()
'foobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobar'
>>>
```

[Python 2.7.1]

```
>python -mtimeit -s"s='The quick brown Fox jumped over the lazy dogs'" "''.join(c.lower() for c in s if not c.isspace())"
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.7 usec per loop

>python27\python -mtimeit -s"s='The quick brown Fox jumped over the lazy dogs'" "''.join(  i.lower() for i  in s.split()  )"
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.11 usec per loop

>python27\python -mtimeit -s"s='The quick brown Fox jumped over the lazy dogs'" "''.join( map(str.lower, s.split() )  )"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.43 usec per loop

>\python27\python -mtimeit -s"s='The quick brown Fox jumped over the lazy dogs'" "''.join(s.split()).lower()"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1 usec per loop
```

Comment: +1, indeed fastest I seen so far. confirmed with timeit module using 250k iterations 0.403948068619s using split, 0.585318088531s using map. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> string=""" a b      c
... D E         F
...                     g
... """
>>> ''.join(  i.lower() for i  in string.split()  )
'abcdefg'
>>>
```

OR

```
>>> ''.join( map(str.lower, string.split() )  )
'abcdefg'
```

Comment: Your join split solution is still a lot slower than John Machin's answer, clocked it at 0.733391046524s for 250k reps using timeit, vs 0.413959026337s for his solution. Going with fastest!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> test = """AB    cd KLM
    RST l
    K"""
 >>> re.sub('\s+','',test).lower()
  'abcdklmrstlk'
```

Comment: This seems tobe the slowest of the bunch, 0.809034109116s on 250k iterations vs John Machin's solution at 0.411396980286s. Map was also faster than this at 0.582627058029s.

Comment: +1.  Finally, someone answered the OPs question (partially)!  Yes, regex is not the correct approach for this problem, however it is still worth knowing.  A good response should be, it is not necessary, but here is how you would do it...

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

```py
your_string.replace(" ","").lower()
```